# Reading from .txt and storing into Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, java-io

Can I use any other approach to read the semicolon separated string from .txt file into Has map instead of  **sourceArra**y

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        ArrayList<Synset> booleansynsets = null;
        ArrayList<Synset> booleanduplicatesynsets = null;
        Map<String, String> basebooleanentitieslist = new HashMap<String, String>();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\anand\\Desktop\\updatedDuplicateBooleanEntitiesList-sorted.txt"));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] sourceArray = line.split(";");
            basebooleanentitieslist.put(sourceArray[0],sourceArray[1]);
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```

**// the updated one**

```
bufferedReader.toString();
        StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(bufferedReader.toString(),";");
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null && st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
  //                String[] sourceArray = line.split(";");

            basebooleanentitieslist.put(st1.nextToken(";"), st1.nextToken());
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```

Comment: What is problem with (current) this approach?

Comment: Your approach is very simple and straight forward, over-optimizing will only make it complicated.

Comment: no problem with the current approach, but was feeling whether its lenghty, i mean is there a way to optimize it without using  sourceArray.

Comment: thanq u guyz for you comments..  if you possible can you guyz pls guide me  how can i do that with stringtokenizer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> no problem with the current approach, but was feeling whether its lengthy, i mean is there a way to optimize it without using sourceArray.

You don't say what you are trying to optimize for: performance? memory usage? readability?

If you are concerned about performance, the next question is whether your concern is actually justified.  Have you run your application?  Is it too slow?  Have you profiled it and determined that splitting the lines is taking a significant amount of time?

What specifically is wrong with using an array?  (Yes, I know that allocating an array costs something, but have you any evidence that this is significant?)

---

If you are trying to optimize for readability, then I'd say that using String.split is probably more readable for this example.  (Many Java programmers have never come across / used the `StringTokenizer` class.)

If you are trying to optimize for performance / memory usage, then `StringTokenizer` is worth trying, but I wouldn't guarantee it is faster.  Another alternative is to use `Pattern` and `Matcher` directly as follows:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^;]*);(.*)");
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line)
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            basebooleanentitieslist.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
        }
    }
```

(By the way, the code about will handle the case where the line doesn't split gracefully; i.e. without throwing an exception.  If you want to deal with it explicitly, add an `else` clause.)

Comment: thanx stephen... your explanation on performance is kool.... i got the point...;)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `StringTokenizer` class.

Comment: Please think your new code through. Your original code was almost right, you read a line and then split the like into tokens. When you use StringTokenizer, you should check hasToken() before using nextToken() as there might be some error in your input were the token is not there and you want to fail gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringTokenizer` (or) Split.